# Frame title using shell-command

Tags: frames

I try to do a shell command in frame-title-format.

```
(setq frame-title-format
      (list (format "%s" (shell-command-to-string (concat "ls -1 %f")))))
```

> ls: cannot access filename: No such file or directory

is shown up on the frame-title.

Is it due to the white space?  How can I fix this?

-Ben

Answer (score 2):

First drop the `format` and `concat`, they don't do anything here.

```
(format "%s" (shell-command-to-string (concat "ls -1 %f")))
```

is essentially the same as

```
(shell-command-to-string "ls -1 %f")
```

---

`%f` and other %-constructs are only meaningful at the time they are *used* to actually generate the frame title from the value of `frame-title-format`. But you are using `%f` at the time the value of that variable is *set*.

Just because you set the value of `frame-title-format` to the value returned by `(shell-command-to-string "ls -1 %f")` doesn't magically assign any special meaning to `%f`. So essentially you do this:

```
$ ls -1 %f
ls: cannot access %f: No such file or directory
```

You are calling `shell-command-to-string` *once*, when you set the value of `frame-title-format`. But what you want to do is to add an element which causes `shell-command-to-string` to be called *every time* the value of `frame-title-format` is *used*, e.g.:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '((:eval (shell-command-to-string "echo -n 'hello frame'"))))
```

---

Moving on to the next issue.

As we have seen above you cannot use `%f` because it has no meaning to `ls`. But this isn't quite right either:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '((:eval (shell-command-to-string
                (format "ls -1 '%s'" buffer-file-name)))))
```

because only buffers that visit a file have a non-nil `buffer-file-name`. So you would have to use something else for other buffers:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '((:eval (if buffer-file-name
                   (shell-command-to-string
                    (format "ls -1 '%s'" buffer-file-name))
                 "something else"))))
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that %f is ambigous
You can try this:

```el
(setq frame-title-format (format "%s" (shell-command-to-string(concat "ls -l " (buffer-file-name)))))
```